# How to exclude many-to-one relationship using hibernate reverse engineering?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, reverse-engineering

I've two tables user and patient. Patient have a user id in it i.e user_id F.K to user.id.

When I create a model classes using reverse engineering, in User model it create Set but in that I need only Patient. My business model says one-to-one relationship between user & patient.

so is there a way to do it ?

Below is table schema.

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,     
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Unique_Email_Id` (`user_email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci



CREATE TABLE `patient` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PATIENT_EMAIL_ID_UNIQUE_ID` (`email_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_USER_ID` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `User_Id_Foreign_Key_To_Patient_Id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**hibernate.reveng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <type-mapping>
        <sql-type jdbc-type="BIT" hibernate-type="int"></sql-type>
    </type-mapping> 
    <table-filter match-name="user">
    <table-filter match-name="patient"></table-filter>
    <table name="patient">          
        <foreign-key constraint-name="Unique_user_Id">          
            <many-to-one exclude="true"/>
        </foreign-key>
    </table>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem using a personalized strategy. For this we have to follow the following steps:
1-New dependence on maven:

```
<!-- Hibernate tools para estrategia presonalizada -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

2-Create custom strategy class (CustomReverseEngineeringStrategy) extending from DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy.

```
package com.xxx.model.strategy;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy;
import org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.ReverseEngineeringStrategy;
import org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.TableIdentifier;

public class CustomReverseEngineeringStrategy extends DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy {
...
}
```

3-Overwrite excludeForeignKeyAsManytoOne method, where we will set a criteria based on which we will indicate which manytoone relationships must be taken into account and which ones are not:

```
@Override
public boolean excludeForeignKeyAsManytoOne(String keyname, TableIdentifier fromTable, List<?> fromColumns, TableIdentifier referencedTable, List<?> referencedColumns) {
    return referencedTable.getName().startsWith(EXCLUDED_REFERED_TABLE_PREFIX);
}
```

4-Adapt the configuration 'hibernate code generation' to make use of the customized strategy:
[image]

Unfortunately, the exclude annotation does not seem to work.

I hope this solution is useful. Using the personalized strategy can achieve many things because we can overwrite multiple methods that control almost all aspects of the reverse generation of entities.